# About MPLS label range

Tags: vpn, router, switch, bgp, mpls

In most routers or switches that support MPLS, if transit label and uhp LSP label need to have a different label range? when protocol(LDP or BGP) assign labels, I know that VPN label and LSP tunnel label have different range, **but I'm not very clear if transit label and termination LSP label have different label range?**

Answer (score 2):

An MPLS label is a 20-bit field, so the range is 0 to 1048575.  There is no set definition for values for a specific purpose, so every manufacturer does it differently.  Cisco, among others, allows you to modify the label ranges to suit your needs.